# Compiling .NET code into one EXE and the other namespaces into DLLs

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, service, namespaces

I have written a windows service.  The windows service has it's own namespace, obviously.  I have 3 other namespaces that I have written that have their respective classes.

When I debug and build the solution it compiles all of the namespaces into the executable file.  Is there a way in Visual Studio to explicitly have namespaces get compiled into separate DLLs?  And just have the main startup namespace in the EXE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've just got one project. Just create two or more projects - one Windows Service project and one or more class library projects. Put the code for the service in its project, and the rest in the class library project or projects. It's up to you whether you create one assembly per namespace or lump all the other code into one class library.

Comment: At this point in development, is it just as simple as moving the *.cs code files to these newly created projects?  If this were a new application it would be simple, but it is quite a bit of code/files.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as moving the *.cs files. The only annoying thing about moving files between projects is that with plain VS you need to fix the namespace.

Comment: Surfer513: It should be as straightforward as that, yes - either drag and drop in solution explorer (I think) or just move them on the file system and use "Add Existing Item".

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces and projects are unrelated as far as the compiler is concerned. That assembly names correspond to namespaces is purely a convention and quite often not followed.

In .net one executable is one assembly and usually one project. So if you want want dlls create a "Class Library" project for them and put the corresponding source code in them.